# Wifi not working on Windows 10

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

I have got MSI prestige PS42 Modern 8MO, Win 10 1903

I am on college network, Until this afternoon my Wifi was working fine but now the Wifi shows no internet, secured on the laptop.

The Wifi is working fine on my mobile.

Things I have tried:

- Uninstalling Wifi drivers.
- network reset,
- update driver,
- power management off,
- system restore,
- device manager tweaks to turn device off and on,
- restart wifi adapter,
- netsh reset and IP release and renew
- and everything I could find online.

Can someone help me now ?

```
ipconfig

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c9a9:1cd4:198a:fdda%20
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.253.218
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Wireless hardware : Intel Wireless -AC 9560 160Mhz

Comment: NO physical switch, I can connect to wifi but it says "no internet,secured"

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting from the network and re-connecting (not sure why that works, but it's specific to Windows 10)?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik that's not correct. This is definitely not caused by a bad cable or password issue. Google "169.254" and read about what causes APIPA addresses to be self assigned.

Comment: @YashKumarAtri this is caused by a problem with the router on the college network. What does the IP address assigned to your mobile device look like? We can use a slightly different variation of that address as a short-term fix for your laptop, to get you online immediately.

Comment: Please edit your question and indicate if you have a Intel Centrino 6205/6235 and Broadcom 802.11ac wireless adapter installed

Comment: The IT cell filtered my MAC address, now it is working fine, Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your laptop. This is happening due to a problem on the network.

That `169.254.x.x` address is what's called an APIPA (Automatic Private IP Addressing) address.

A network card assigns itself an APIPA address when the network that it's connected to is unable to provide an IP address via DHCP. APIPA is a fallback system that provides basic connectivity on the local network but its addresses are non-routable, meaning that any device using such an address will have no internet access.

Possible causes:

- the DHCP server on the router has stopped functioning and needs to be restarted by the IT department
- there are so many other wireless clients on the network that all of the available IP addresses in the DHCP scope have already been assigned to other clients

**Quick workaround:**

- statically assign an IP address on your laptop's wireless network card (you may need to try a couple of different addresses if your first attempt conflicts with an existing device on the network).
- as a last resort, you could always disable WiFi on your phone and assign the same IP address that your phone was using to your laptop. This would restore internet connectivity to your laptop and would ensure that no IP address conflicts can occur.

**Long-term solution:**

- talk to the IT department responsible for managing your college's network as soon as possible and explain that you have a device that is unable to get an IP address through DHCP. Tell them that you're getting a `169.254` address. Other people are probably affected and they may need to restart the router or DHCP service on the server to fix the underlying problem.

**Why is the phone able to acquire an IP address from the DHCP server but not the laptop?**

Most likely explanations:

- the phone had already acquired an IP address via DHCP before the DHCP service crashed
- the phone had already acquired an IP address via DHCP before the last available IP address was allocated to a wireless client

Comment: This is just an add-on. This post helped me out to start probing my system. The TL;DR is my VPN software was not properly starting and eventually crashed. When it crashed my WiFi was "No Internet, Connected" as Win10 was expecting it. WiFi worked fine when I booted to Linux. Trying to use my mobile hotspot (or any) in Win10 didn't help. Took a bit for me to figure it out.